# Listening for tables and call function if something changes

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

i'm trying to build an application which makes decision totally based on changes in specific tables in my database. For example:

```
Email        service listening to changes in email table
Notification service listening to changes in event table
```

In the other hand i have my API database service, which serves to create, update, read and delete data using REST. So, my architecture is like an inverse triangle (i like to thing that way), in the base i have my client, in the left side i have my API database service and in the right i have my other application that listening to changes in specific tables. The problem is: i don't have idea how to listening to changes in the tables in my database, so i'm trying to figure it out the logic behind (not the code), and if there is any package to help me achieve what i want.. and finally, what you guys think about this architecture?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not the best solution but you can ping the db after a specific interval and and then send updated data to connected clients using socket.io etc.

There maybe some tools or packages to listen db changes and triggering some function but since it is technology dependent.